# Can't Get Location using LocationManager in Background Service

Tags: android, service, location

I have created an application that stores your location in database at periodic time in Background service but, it doesn't get location. my code  is...

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

    private Double myLat, myLong;
    private Location location;
    private LocationManager locManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private boolean NETWORK_ENABLED, GPS_ENABLED, PASSIVE_ENABLED;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        myLat = 0.00;
        myLong = 0.00;
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                LocationService.this.location = location;
                LocationService.this.myLat = location.getLatitude();
                LocationService.this.myLong = location.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onLocationChanged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                insertToDatabase();
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {}
        };

        getMyCurrentLocation();

    }

    private void getMyCurrentLocation() {
        location = null;
        locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        NETWORK_ENABLED = false; GPS_ENABLED = false; PASSIVE_ENABLED = false;
        NETWORK_ENABLED = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (NETWORK_ENABLED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network Provider", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 45 * 1000l, 1f, locationListener);
        } 
        if (location == null) {
            //setGPSOn();
            GPS_ENABLED = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(GPS_ENABLED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Provider", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0l, 1f, locationListener);
            }
            //setGPSOff();
        } 
        if (location == null) {
            PASSIVE_ENABLED = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
            if(PASSIVE_ENABLED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passive Provider", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0l, 1f, locationListener);
            }
        }
        try {
            location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(locManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true));
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {}
        if (location != null) {
            myLat = location.getLatitude();
            myLong = location.getLongitude();
            insertToDatabase();
        } else {
            Location loc = null;
            try {
                loc = getLastKnownLocation(this);
            } catch(NullPointerException e) {}
            if (loc != null) {
                myLat = loc.getLatitude();
                myLong = loc.getLongitude();
                insertToDatabase();
            }
        }
        locManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }

    private Location getLastKnownLocation(Context context) {
        Location location = null;
        LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService("location");
        List<?> list = locationmanager.getAllProviders();
        boolean i = false;
        Iterator<?> iterator = list.iterator();
        do {
            if(!iterator.hasNext())
                break;
            String s = (String)iterator.next();
            if(i != false && !locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(s))
                continue;
            Location location1 = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(s);
            if(location1 == null)
                continue;
            else {
                float f = location.getAccuracy();
                float f1 = location1.getAccuracy();
                if(f >= f1) {
                    long l = location1.getTime();
                    long l1 = location.getTime();
                    if(l - l1 <= 600000L)
                        continue;
                }
            }
            location = location1;
            i = locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(s);
        } while (true);
        return location;
    }
}
```

this doesn't give me any location.... and my app is also doesn't Crash or gives any Exception.

I have properly register all permissions in Manifest file...
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

I can't find what to do?
any help will be appreciated
thanks in advance for Help...

Comment: Did toasts  "Network Provider" or "GPS Provider" show?

Comment: Yes! all of 3 toasts are shown when i run the application. but, no one provider stores data in my database.

Comment: Try to enable only one, preferably the Network Provider one and check.

Comment: I've try using only Network Provider but, nothing Happen

Comment: dont remove the listeners before you get anything, see my answer

Comment: You were Right! after removing locManager.removeUpdates(locationListener); it working properly! i also got latitude and longitude in my database... but, problem is that application still shows all 3 providers toast!, so, it's hard to determine from which provider i have got location?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you remove the listener right away:

```
locManager.removeUpdates(locationListener); // comment this one out
```

in `getMyCurrentLocation()`;

You should try to remove your listener in some other places.

Comment: You were Right! after removing locManager.removeUpdates(locationListener); it working properly! i also got latitude and longitude in my database... but, problem is that application still shows all 3 providers toast!, so, it's hard to determine from which provider i have got location?